# Is there an easy way to extract the parameters of a form routine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, typescript

I am looking for Regex to extract the parameters of a SAP Form Routine.

The Form routine signature looks like the following:

```
FORM get_vbrk_data USING cs_bil_number TYPE VBELN CHANGING cs_vbrk TYPE vbrk cs_vbak TYPE vbak.
```

Challenge here is to get the name of the FORM routine -> get_vbrk_data

... AND the parameters:

USING -> cs_bil_number TYPE VBELN

CHANGING ->  cs_vbrk TYPE vbrk AND cs_vbak TYPE vbak

The perfect format would be an result array with the following format:

[
"get_vbrk_data",
"USING",
"cs_bil_number",
"TYPE",
"VBELN",
"CHANGING",
"cs_vbrk",
"TYPE",
"vbrk",
"cs_vbak",
"TYPE",
"vbak"
]

I tried to start with the following Regex:

```
\b(?:USING|CHANGING).*
```

But I am not able to process further.

Comment: Do not use regex, use a proper parser.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for replay. What proper parser do you recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observing your *perfect format*, you don't actually *extract the parameters*, but rather simply divide the *Form routine* without the leading `FORM`  and the trailing `.` into its substrings:

```js
s = "FORM get_vbrk_data USING cs_bil_number TYPE VBELN CHANGING cs_vbrk TYPE vbrk cs_vbak TYPE vbak."
console.log(s.slice(5, -1).split(' '))
```

Comment: Smart move! Thanks for sharing :-) I was thinking all the time about a perfect regex, but slicing the string into substrings makes sense, thank you!